# Calculating Op Amp gain with voltage divider

Tags: operational-amplifier, power-electronics

Is there a gain differences between schematic 1 and 2? For schematic 1, the gain would be $$-\frac{R2}{R1} = -\frac{100k}{1m} = -0.1$$ But what about the schematic 2?

**Schematic 1:**

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGso2o.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**Schematic 2:**

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKg1DK.png)</sup>

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: It has the same gain.

Comment: Really? Then what is the function of R3 and R4?

Comment: The function of R3 and R4 is to test you whether you understand how opamp works or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both circuits have the same gain.
**R4** is simply just a load, connected to opamp's output. You can ignore it. Remember that output impedance of opamp si very low.
**R3** is simply a resistor put between 0V and 0V, there is no current flowing through it, so you can ignore it too. Remember that opamp tries to keep inverting and noninverting input at the same voltage.

Comment: thanks for the explanation, so there's no voltage divider rules applied here?

Comment: No. It is not a voltage divider. You have to understand how an opamp works.

Comment: Yes - the VALUE of the gain is (practically) given by R1 and R2 only. However, the BANDWIDTH of the amplfier is reduced due to a smaller loop gain (less feedback).

Comment: LvW, if you want to be a detailist, you could consider output impedance, input offset, input bias current, and so on. Everything matters in that case and has impact on gain a little bit. But I think it is irrelevant for this type of question.

Comment: If R3 (across the input pins) were a series RC, you would affect the high-frequency gain/phase and thus the stability or propensity to oscillate. But with just a resistor, you get a tiny error because Vin- is not exactly ZERO volts; you can model this and determine the error.

Comment: While R4 may simply be a load, the open loop output impedance of this op-amp is typically 40 ohms, so don't be surprised if a 100 ohm load causes some strange things to happen on output swings. In addition, this load will cause more current to be drawn. I speak from experience that this sort of loading can produce "entertaining" output squeaks, squawks, and oscillations.